# Update row with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-update

So I want to be able to update a row in my table. I know how to do this

```
UPDATE Param                
SET(Param1=@Param1, Param2=@Param2, Param3=@Param3, ...)
WHERE ParamId = @ParamId
```

The problem is that I don't know which column will be updated and which isn't, it depends on what the user changed. And I have a lot of param to to check.

```
--idk if this will work, I am just trying to limit the amont of code posted
ISNULL(@Param1, Select Param1 from Param where WHERE ParamId = @ParamId)
```

I was thinking about dynamic SQL, but it poses to much of a security risk. Is there a way for me to do this faster? Or is there no way around this? If you need more info please ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `COALESCE`/`ISNULL` but you don't need to select the old value as default as sub query, you can use it directly:

```
UPDATE Param                
SET Param1=COALESCE(@Param1,Param1), Param2=COALESCE(@Param2,Param2), ...
WHERE ParamId = @ParamId
```

However,on this way you cannot set a nullable column to `NULL`. I assume this is desired.

Comment: Interesting I did not know that one. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx So it will know that Param1 is the value in column Param1 at the specified row without me needing to explicitly tell it cool.

Comment: I still need to be able to set some of the column to be nullable. Sorry did not see the last sentence.

Comment: @JackThor: No, you have to specify the `COALESCE` for every column as i've shown above.If you need to be able to set a column to null you can't use this approach and you habve to specify a parameter for all columns.

Comment: So then I can't do this `UPDATE Param                
SET Param1=ISNULL(@Param1,Param1), Param2=ISNULL(@Param2,Param2), ...
WHERE ParamId = @ParamId`

Comment: You can, it's my approach above. But then you cannot update with `NULLS` since this would replace the null with the current value of the column, hence it remains unchanged.